# Convert SQL request to Django ORM request

Tags: sql, django-models

I have a simple model in django

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class Message(models.Model):
    message_num = models.IntegerField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join([
            str(self.id),
            ' ',
            str(self.message_num),
            ' ',
            self.name
        ])


class MessageVersion(models.Model):
    message_id = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    version_num = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    text = models.TextField()
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I want to select the latest MessageVersion for Message. In pure SQL it`s simple

```
select res1.*, res2.* from homepage_messageversion res1
join (
    select message_id_id, max(version_num) as version_num
    from homepage_messageversion
    group by message_id_id
) res2
on (res1.message_id_id = res2.message_id_id)
and (res1.version_num = res2.version_num);
```

How to correct conwert this SQL request to Django ORM request?

Answer (score 1):

Django ORM is also quite simple. You can do it like this.

First get the Message object for which you want the latest VersionMessage. For example i will get the message object for id 1.

`message = Message.objects.get(id=1)`

Now get all the message versions for the above message, and order by creation time.

`message_versions = MessageVersion.objects.filter(message_id=message).order_by('-created')`

Right now you have all the message versions, now get the latest one

`message_version_latest = message_versions[0]`

Hope this help.